# Join two child records next to each other in one row in PL Sql

Tags: sql, oracle, join

I have 2 tables,

```
select * from Srn_Table1;
```

| ID | CUSTOMERNAME |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | TEST CUSTOMER |

```
select * from Srn_Table2;
```

| ID | ADDRESS | ADDRESSID |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | palakkad | 1 |
| 1 | thrissur | 2 |

I need the Result as

| ID | ADDRESS | ADDRESSID | ADDRESS | ADDRESSID |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | palakkad | 1 | thrissur | 2 |

ID is common.

How can I join the 2 tables to get the result..?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would add a row number to the second table, so that you can join that table once for when that row number is 1, and a second time for when it is 2:

```
with ext as (
    select Srn_Tablea2.*, 
           row_number() over (partition by id order by addressid) rn
    from   Srn_Tablea2
)
select    a.id, b.address, b.addressid, c.address, c.addressid
from      Srn_Tablea1 a
left join ext b on a.id = b.id and b.rn = 1
left join ext c on a.id = c.id and c.rn = 2;
```

Of course, if you have cases where you have 3 or more addresses for the same `id`, you'll have to create more joins, and produce more columns. But the principle remains the same.